# updating sqlite database in javafx app

Tags: sqlite, javafx, fxml

I have created a javafx app and embedded sqlite database, The database needs to be updated time to time. Is there some way i can set up so that I can update the database from one sever PC and the same gets updated on all the PC's where the app is installed

Comment: All the computers must be connected to the network.Regularly your application installed on every computer is searching for updates.Although `mysql` has to be used here.Many scenarios exist,although the critical is the computers to be connected on the network(LAN , Internet...).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion , all the computers will be on n/w 24/7 that won't be an issue. But isn't there any way that I can achieve using just SQLITE..

Comment: Copying the database from one client to the server ;) (crazy though) or somehow all the computers have access to the computer containg the database? Although why you don't use MySQL that's the purpose it was made for.Have a look at some perfect tutorials on youtube ...